# Compiling TypeScript Project: Separate Bundle for npm Modules, Main Code Excluded from Bundle

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, bundle, building

I want to compile a project where I will use TypeScript and npm modules that should be compiled into a separate bundle, while the main code of my application should not be in the bundle (as if it was compiled with tsc)

I tried using Webpack but I couldn't get the desired behavior